# How to get random choice from a list as a variable?

Tags: python

I WAS RUNNING PYTHON 2 FOR SOME WEIRD REASON CHANGED IT BACK TO PYTHON 3 IN MY EDITOR AND IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS

Hey guys I'm trying to make this simple guessing game where random.choice returns an item from the list and the user has to guess it. The problem I'm having is when I get the user input I get the error that the guess is a name error and was not defined. I would also like for the user to keep guessing if he guesses wrong. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please and thank you for taking the time to help me out.

```
import random


words = ('apple', 'banana', 'cherry')
word = random.choice(words)
guess = input("gues the word either apple banana or cherry: ")



if guess == word:
    print("you won")
elif guess != word:
    print("you lost")
else:
    print("try again")
```

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the `guess` error you claim.  I'm using Python 3.4.5, since your `print` functions imply that you're using Python 3.

Comment: Assuming that you're running this with Python 2.x, you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3? In python2, the `input` function attempts to evaluate whatever you type in. For python2, you can use `raw_input` instead, which will store the input as a string. For python 3, `raw_input` was replaced by `input`. Switch to python3 while you're new!!

Comment: THIS FIXED IT THANK YOU I WAS ON PYTHON 2 ON ACCIDENT

Answer (score 1):

`words = ('apple', 'banana', 'cherry')`

should be

`words = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']`

to make it a list.

To continue guessing you'll want to build something with a `while` loop.  In general StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, but a place to specific bugs or for people to get you going in the right direction.  Do do that, I would suggest becoming familiar with the basic data structures, take this class for example:

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python

It's a great place to start (where I learned the basics) and is free.  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question or address the problem and should probably be a comment instead.

Comment: ah, good call.  I read that too quickly.  I'll try and update it a bit with more stuff.  I think it would be too long as a simple comment (perhaps a series of comments?)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

words = ('apple', 'banana', 'cherry')
word = random.choice(words)

#Once the condition has been met, use break:
while True:
    guess = input("gues the word either apple banana or cherry: ")
    if guess == word:
        print("you won")
        break
    else:
        print("you lost, try again")
```

in your case there is no sense to have elif and else statement, it will never reach else block:

```
if guess == word:
    print("you won")
elif guess != word: # if guess is different than word it will print "you lost" and go out from if-elif-else statement it will never reach else block
    print("you lost")
else:
    print("try again")
```

Comment: WOW DIDN'T EVEN NOTICE THAT MY INTERPRETER WAS SET TO PYTHON 2 JUST CHANGED IT TO PYTHON 3 AND IT WORKED THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH YOU ARE ALL THE BEST ON HERE